# Why is one of the selectors in Flexslider working and the second one isn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I am trying to use two selectors in Wootheme's Flexslider inside wordpress, because I need to use different styles for my slides on different pages.

When I add this line to the slider's code,

selector: ".slides > li, .my_slides > li"

.sldes > li,  - is working fine, but .my_slides -  isn't working.

Here is the link to the sliders code:
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js

Here is the the code where I use .slides and .my_slides:

```
/* *********** (12) Display Post Format ******** */

    function swm_display_post_format() {

        $format = get_post_format();

        if(empty($format)) {
            $format = 'standard';
        }
        if( $format == 'standard' || $format == 'gallery' || $format == 'image' || $format == 'video' ) {

            get_template_part( 'includes/' . $format );
        }
    }



    /* ************* (13) Blog Gallery Slider ************* */

    if ( !function_exists( 'swm_blog_gallery' ) ) {
        function swm_blog_gallery($postid, $image_size) { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                    if ( $.browser.msie ){
                        if($.browser.version == '8.0') {
                             $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").flexslider({
                                slideshow: false,
                                controlNav: true,
                                smoothHeight: true,
                                start: function(slider) {
                                    slider.container.click(function(event) {
                                        if( !slider.animating ) slider.flexAnimate( slider.getTarget('next') );
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }


                   $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").imagesLoaded( function() {
                    $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").flexslider({
                        slideshow: false,
                        controlNav: true,
                        smoothHeight: true,
                        start: function(slider) {
                            slider.container.click(function(event) {
                                if( !slider.animating ) slider.flexAnimate( slider.getTarget('next') );
                            });
                        }
                    });
                   });
                });
            </script>
            <?php

            $gal_images = rwmb_meta( 'swm_pf_gallery_photos', 'type=thickbox_image' );
            $meta_gallery_img_height = rwmb_meta( 'swm_meta_gallery_img_height');

            echo "<div class='pf_featured_img pf_l_img'><div class='swm_slider_box'><div id='flex-$postid' class='flexslider pfi_gallery'>";


            if ( $gal_images ) {
                echo "<ul class='slides'>";

                foreach ( $gal_images as $gal_image ) {
                   //   $swm_gal_image = "{$gal_image['url']}";
                    $swm_gal_image = swm_resize($gal_image['url'], 635, 425,  $meta_gallery_img_height, true,'c',true);
                        echo "<li><img src='$swm_gal_image' alt='' /></li>";
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
            echo "</div></div></div>";
        }
    }





    /* **************** (12) Display MY Post Format **************************** */

    function swm_display_my_post_format() {

        $format = 'gallery1';

        get_template_part( 'includes/' . $format );
    }



    /* ***********************(13) Blog MY Gallery Slider *********************** */

    if ( !function_exists( 'swm_my_blog_gallery' ) ) {
        function swm_my_blog_gallery($postid, $image_size) { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                    if ( $.browser.msie ){
                        if($.browser.version == '8.0') {
                            $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").flexslider({
                                slideshow: true,
                                controlNav: true,
                                smoothHeight: true,
                                start: function(slider) {
                                    slider.container.click(function(event) {
                                        if( !slider.animating ) slider.flexAnimate( slider.getTarget('next') );
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }


                    $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").imagesLoaded( function() {
                        $("#flex-<?php echo $postid; ?>").flexslider({
                            slideshow: true,
                            controlNav: true,
                            smoothHeight: true,
                            start: function(slider) {
                                slider.container.click(function(event) {
                                    if( !slider.animating ) slider.flexAnimate( slider.getTarget('next') );
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <?php

            $gal_images = rwmb_meta( 'swm_pf_gallery_photos', 'type=thickbox_image' );
            $meta_gallery_img_height = rwmb_meta( 'swm_meta_gallery_img_height');

            echo "<div class='pf_featured_img pf_l_img'><div class='my_swm_slider_box'><div id='flex-$postid' class='flexslider pfi_gallery'>";

            if ( $gal_images ) {
                echo "<ul class='my_slides'>";

                foreach ( $gal_images as $gal_image ) {
                    //  $swm_gal_image = "{$gal_image['url']}";
                    $swm_gal_image = swm_resize($gal_image['url'], 510, 410,  $meta_gallery_img_height, true,'c',true);
                    echo "<li><img src='$swm_gal_image' alt='' /></li>";
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
            echo "</div></div></div>";
        }
    }
```

This is generated HTML where it is working:

```
     <div class="best_img_wrap">
            <div class="best_img">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                        if ($.browser.msie) {
                            if ($.browser.version == '8.0') {
                                $("#flex-42").flexslider({
                                    slideshow: false,
                                    controlNav: true,
                                    smoothHeight: true,
                                    start: function (slider) {
                                        slider.container.click(function (event) {
                                            if (!slider.animating) slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget('next'));
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }


                        $("#flex-42").imagesLoaded(function () {
                            $("#flex-42").flexslider({
                                slideshow: false,
                                controlNav: true,
                                smoothHeight: true,
                                start: function (slider) {
                                    slider.container.click(function (event) {
                                        if (!slider.animating) slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget('next'));
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
            </script>
                <div class="pf_featured_img pf_l_img">
                    <div class="swm_slider_box">
                        <div class="flexslider pfi_gallery" id="flex-42" style="height: 425px;">
                            <ul class="slides">
                                <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1;
                                    display: block; z-index: 2;" class="flex-active-slide">
                                    <img alt="" src="http://localhost/inst_new/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Untitled-5-0x0_1.jpg"
                                        draggable="false"></li><li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%;
                                            position: relative; opacity: 0; display: block; z-index: 1;">
                                            <img alt="" src="http://localhost/inst_new/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/rp_11-0x0_1.jpg"
                                                draggable="false"></li><li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%;
                                                    position: relative; opacity: 0; display: block; z-index: 1;">
                                                    <img alt="" src="http://localhost/inst_new/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/violin-0x0_1.jpg"
                                                        draggable="false"></li></ul>
                            <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
                                <li><a class="flex-active">1</a></li><li><a>2</a></li><li><a>3</a></li></ol>
                            <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
                                <li><a href="#" class="flex-prev">Previous</a></li><li><a href="#" class="flex-next">
                                    Next</a></li></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is generated HTML where it is NOT working:

```
<div class="my_post_wrapper">
        <p>
        </p>
        <div class="caty_name">
            <a rel="category" title="View all posts in Crack Repairs" href="http://localhost/inst_new/?cat=8">
                Crack Repairs</a></div>
        <p>
        </p>
        <div class="my_post_title">
            <h3>
                <a title="Permanent Link to Recent Post 3 + Crack Repair" href="http://localhost/inst_new/?p=64"
                    class="service_single_title"></a>
                <div class="caty_title">
                    <a title="Permanent Link to Recent Post 3 + Crack Repair" href="http://localhost/inst_new/?p=64"
                        class="service_single_title">Recent Post 3 + Crack Repair</a></div>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <!-- .post title -->
        <div class="my_post_content featured_post">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                    if ($.browser.msie) {
                        if ($.browser.version == '8.0') {
                            $("#flex-64").flexslider({
                                slideshow: true,
                                controlNav: true,
                                smoothHeight: true,
                                start: function (slider) {
                                    slider.container.click(function (event) {
                                        if (!slider.animating) slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget('next'));
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }


                    $("#flex-64").imagesLoaded(function () {
                        $("#flex-64").flexslider({
                            slideshow: true,
                            controlNav: true,
                            smoothHeight: true,
                            start: function (slider) {
                                slider.container.click(function (event) {
                                    if (!slider.animating) slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget('next'));
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
        </script>
            <div class="pf_featured_img pf_l_img">
                <div class="my_swm_slider_box">
                    <div class="flexslider pfi_gallery" id="flex-64">
                        <ul class="my_slides">
                            <li>
                                <img alt="" src="http://localhost/inst_new/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Untitled-1-0x0_1.jpg"></li><li>
                                    <img alt="" src="http://localhost/inst_new/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Untitled-71-0x0_1.jpg"></li></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
                <a class="white_button" href="http://localhost/inst_new/?p=64">Read more &gt;&gt;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Flexslider looks for the class "slides" on the UL. This is the case on your first example, on the second it is "my_slides".

You can change the class on the second slider UL, or you can specify the selector when you initialize flexslider, like this:

```
                $("#flex-64").imagesLoaded(function () {
                    $("#flex-64").flexslider({
                        slideshow: true,
                        controlNav: true,
                        smoothHeight: true,
                        selector: '.my_slides > li',
                        start: function (slider) {
                            slider.container.click(function (event) {
                                if (!slider.animating) slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget('next'));
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Edit: I think I missed a piece of your question. If I understand correctly, you're trying to provide Flexslider with two different selectors for it to potentially act on? This should work, but it's not represented in your code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you, Mikeharty!! I think, sepcifying selector at innitialization  it's what I need!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You understood my question right, drop down menu problem seems not to be related to this selector. It's something else that appeared while I was trying to fix problem with slider :)

Comment: Yes exactly, it was something different) Thank you again! you really saved me A LOT of time and energy!! I am new to Javascript, it's the second day I was struggling with this problem! :)